# F# spawn a new async request every second

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

My goal (before I expand on it) is to start up an Async task (in this case, fetching a URL) once a second. The idea is that if the Async task takes 3 seconds, it would behave like this:

```
0sec: Start thread 0
1sec: Start thread 1
2sec: Start thread 2
3sec: Start thread 3
3sec: Finish thread 0
4sec: Start thread 4
4sec: Finish thread 1
```

Here's my code so far. The workTime and Async.Sleep code was added to make my problem more apparent.

```
let FetchUrlAsync (thread: int) (url: string) =
    async {
        let req = WebRequest.Create(url)
        let! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)

        let workTime = System.Random().Next(5000,8000)
        sprintf "start work %i" thread |> Console.WriteLine
        do! Async.Sleep workTime
        sprintf "end work %i (time taken: %i)" thread workTime |> Console.WriteLine
        return reader.ReadToEnd()
    }

Seq.initInfinite(fun i -> FetchUrlAsync i "http://www.google.com"
                          |> Async.StartAsTask
                          |> ignore
                          Thread.Sleep 1000
                )
|> Seq.iter(id)
```

The issue is that there seems to be a maximum of two threads running at the same time. Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Also, this is my first time doing anything with async. Please let me know if you see any way to improve my code (is using Thread.Sleep the right thing to do here?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is by default set to 2. Raise its value higher with something like this before your requests:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit <- 10
```

Comment: I'm voting up because it works for my example, but I'm hopeful for other responses. According to [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821268), the limit should be (12*#of CPUs). I anticipate the possibility of many threads running concurrently, and I do not want to be hindered by this limitation

Comment: @rebornprogrammer : This _is_ the correct answer... The fact that _you should_ (probably. (maybe...)) set the limit to CpuN*12 has nothing to do with the simple fact that the default value is, and has been for at least decades, `2`.